# How do I show single/multiple attachments from a XsltListViewWebPart of a list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part

SharePoint 2007, trying to display attachments via an XsltListViewWebPart. Doesn't seem clear on how to accomplish this via designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh. Found the answer I was looking for on [this site](http://dbweb.sbisite.com/blogs/bf/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=19).

Basically:
`<SharePoint:AttachmentsField ControlMode="Display" ItemId="{@ID}" EnableViewState="true" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>`